# Is there a keyword in TypeScript used inside a class to get its type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'd like to refer to the type of the class from inside the class without using it's name

- so I don't need to change my code at multiple places if the name of the class changes,
- my code won't get any longer even if I have long class names,
- and when I see this keyword I know immediately what it refers to without looking up the type.

This is how I have it now:

```
class MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName {

  private myProp: SomeType;

  someMethod() {
    let foo: MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName['myProp']; // to make foo a SomeType
  }

}
```

and here's how I'd like to have it:

```
class MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName {

  private myProp: SomeType;

  someMethod() {
    let foo: thatMagicKeyword['myProp']; // to make foo a SomeType
  }

}
```

Just to illustrate what I want:

```
class MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName {

  private myProp: SomeType;

  someMethod() {
    let foo: (typeof this)['myProp']; // to make foo a SomeType
  }

}
```

that obviously won't work as `typeof` returns just a string.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without repeating `MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName` at least once, since you need to specify the `this` in order to type it properly for the `myProp` self-reference

Comment: If you rename classes using your IDE the first point goes away. And if your class names are too long for you to reference them, aren't they too long for anyone else to reference them and you should pick a better name instead?

Comment: @IngoBürk you're right, however, long is relative. Even if you pick "normal length" names for your classes, if you're in a "framework environment" let's say Angular, some TypeScript keyword for this purpose could spare you quite a lot characters in `MyShortNamedComponent` already.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `public myProp` you can use 'this'

```
class MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName {
    public myProp: SomeType;

    someMethod() {
        let foo: this['myProp']; // to make foo a SomeType
    }
}
```

You can also use a typealias to make the class name shorter, assuming all the classes are in different files.

```
type ThisClass = MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName

export class MyClassThatMightHaveAQuiteLongName {
    public myProp: SomeType;

    someMethod() {
        let foo: ThisClass['myProp']; // to make foo a SomeType
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't know `public` makes this difference. Why is this so? That's exactly what I want but why isn't this option available if the property is `private`?

Comment: @tom `this` is a specific type meant to be returned by a builder method to a user of the class. therefore, it does not include private properties.